# What's the chance that on each day, one student has birthday?

Tags: probability-theory

If a school has 1000 students, what's the probability that for each day in a year, there is some student whos birthday is on that day?

Comment: What do you think about this question? Have you heard of the coupon collector's problem?

Comment: are the days equally probable ?